# How to split a string by regex while keeping the splitter in the array

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'm starting to learn regex in Javascript, can I do that?

Imagine I have the following string:

```
Car ball car ball circle happy
```

And I want to match by all instead of **ball**, an output like:

```
["Car", "car", "circle happy"]
```

Or, split when I find *ball* in my string:

```
["Car", "ball", "car", "ball", "circle happy"]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Sample input doesn't suffice.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Make sure to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure you get high quality answers!

Comment: I mean something like (split only when you find "ball")

Comment: I think you are looking for `s.split(/\b(ball)\b/)`, but then you'd need to get rid of empty elements and trim the rest.

Comment: Thanks for all help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may split with `/(ball)/` (or to account for a whole word, add `\b` word boundary around the pattern). Wrapping the whole pattern with *capturing parentheses* will output the matched string parts into the resulting array.

```js
var s = 'Car ball car ball circle happy';
console.log(s.split(/(ball)/).map(function(x) { return x.trim();}));
```

If you do not need the `ball` to be output in the resulting array, omit the capturing parentheses, use a mere `/ball/`.

If you need to make the pattern case insensitive, use the `/i` modifier: `/(ball)/i`.

Answer (score 2):

You can split by `'ball'` to get your answer as :

```
["Car", "car", "circle happy"]
```

Or by `'(ball)'` to get your answer as :

```
["Car","ball","car","ball","circle happy"]
```

```js
var str="Car ball car ball circle happy";
var vals=str.split(/ball/i).map(String.trim);
console.log(vals);

// Or

var valsAll=str.split(/(ball)/i).map(String.trim);
console.log(valsAll);
```

Comment: You do not need `g` modifier with regex split operation in JavaScript, it is the default behavior.